# UiTextField clipsToBound is setting as true when keyboard comes out

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a text field, when keyboard comes out it, it’s clipstobounds property automatically becomes true. When keyboard goes back it again become false. Any solution to this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Quick test does not show this behavior. Please review [ask] and provide enough detail so we can reproduce the issue -- you may need to create a [mre].

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried into your question. It will increase the chances of you receiving help from others and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.